# Regex retorna strint dentro de corchetes

Tags: python, regex

he estado intentando obtener string tipo:
corrreo@servicio.com:nosepregunten dentro de una lista, sin embargo cuando retorna hace esto:
['correo@service.com:keyword'].
El código es:

```
combos = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+')
combos = combos.findall(res.text)
if combos != []: #evito que se impriman [] sólos
        print(combos)
```

Comment: el res.text es una texto(Eso funciona bien)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El resultado es totalmente el esperado, `re.findall` **[retorna siempre una lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)** de cadenas si no defines grupos en tu expresión:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, **as a list of strings**

los corchetes son la representación de la lista simplemente:

> ```
> >>> l = ["Hola"]
> >>> print(l)
> ['hola']
> ```

Para evitar que se muestren los corchetes debes acceder al item o items de la lista e imprimirlos:

- Puedes indizar, si solo esperas una coincidencia o ninguna:

  ```
  combos_patt = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+')
  combos = combos_patt.findall(res.text)
  if combos:
      print(combos[0])
  ```
- Iterar sobre la lista:

  ```
  combos_patt = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+')
  combos = combos_patt.findall(res.text)
  for combo in combos:
      print(combo)
  ```

Para comprobar si una lista no está vacía no hagas `if lista != []`, esto es poco pitónico además de ineficiente porque se crea un objeto `list` nuevo vacío y se itera sobre ambos para comprobar que sean iguales. Python evalúa como `false` cualquier contenedor vacío, por lo que simplemente debes hacer:

```
if combo:
    ...
```